# Cannot include some angular material files in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I tried to add angular material stuff which files contains `$` like `$data.json`, `$data.js`, etc. to TFS but I got error like: TF10122: Cannot add `..\..\$data.json`

How to solve it ?

Comment: add where, to git or tfvc?

Comment: Is about TFS from Microsoft, no git

Comment: From my research: There’s no need to check in the ‘node_modules’ folder to VSTS and get down it when build. To solve this issue, first you delete the ‘$/xxxxxxxxx/node_modules’ folder in VSTS. Then in build definition, add a npm install task to install those packages for you. Please let me know if it works